# C++ unique_ptr causes Application to crash

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I got a class with one static function. The purpose is to provide a common interface for the application to retrieve a logger object which will log to a specific file (assuming, for now, that a file can not be represented by different filepath notations). Each logger object is stored in a map with it's corresponding filename. Instead of creating a new logger if the same filename is passed again in the `config` object, the old logger is returned:

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<AbstractLogger> LoggerPtr_t;
typedef std::map<std::string, LoggerPtr_t >::iterator LoggerMapIt_t;    
std::map<std::string, LoggerPtr_t> LoggerFactory::mLoggerMap;

LoggerPtr_t LoggerFactory::getGenericLogger(const LoggerConfig& config){
    std::string filename = config.getFileName();    
    LoggerMapIt_t itLogger = mLoggerMap.find(filename);    
    if(itLogger == mLoggerMap.end()){
        mLoggerMap.insert(std::make_pair(filename, LoggerPtr_t(new SimpleLogger(config))));
        itLogger = mLoggerMap.find(filename);
    }    
    //if i uncommend the following 4 lines everything works fine
    if(itLogger != mLoggerMap.end()){
        return std::move(itLogger->second);
    }
    else
    return LoggerPtr_t(new SimpleLogger(config));    
}
```

But it seems that the application crashes if different threads try to write to the same logger. The file (means the `std::ofstream`) is protected by a mutex in the `log` method of `SimpleLogger`. I guess that the `unique_ptr` is the reason. Anyway I would like to have only one pointer to the logger object, because this objects behaves like a unique element (for each file only one logger).

Is it possible that the application crash is caused by the `unique_ptr`? Am I using the `unique_ptr` wrong? Is there a better solution to achieve my intention?

---

EDIT: I got many good answers to this questions. Finally I adapted Jarod's Solution in my Code, but Joe's answer is also very usefull.

Comment: When getGenericLogger() is called with a new filename, you create a new SimpleLogger() object and add it to the map - and then you create a new one again and returns that. You'll probably want to return the first one in that case, and not create yet a new one.

Comment: I create a new Logger object, add it to the map, find the logger in the map and return it with move(itLogger->second) .... at least that was what i intended.

Comment: Do you want to transfer ownership in your method ?

Comment: After all this trouble I'm no longer sure if I fully understand what ownership means in that context. I only want one logger object for each file and that every thread is able to use this logger object. And afterwards, if the map containing all my logger objects is destroyed - the corresponding logger objects should also be destroyed automatically.

Comment: How long should the `Logger` be alive ? if it is as long as the factory, you should return pointer/reference to the `AbstractLogger`. if it is the caller of your method which should destruct your object, then return an `unique_ptr`. if it is the longest time from previous case, `shared_ptr` is appropriate.

Comment: In this case, your are using `unique_ptr` in the wrong way. Thought about using `shared_ptr` instead? Or, if your logger instances in `LoggerFactory::mLoggerMap` will NEVER be removed, you could also decide to return just a reference instead of `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`.

Comment: BTW, regarding thread safeness: Looks that your `LoggerFactory::getGenericLogger()` has to be protected by a mutex against concurrent access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows, how to do with using `std::shared_ptr` (draft, not tested):

```
using LoggerPtr_t = std::shared_ptr<AbstractLogger>;
using LoggerMapIt_t = std::map<std::string, LoggerPtr_t>::iterator;
std::map<std::string, LoggerPtr_t> LoggerFactory::mLoggerMap;

LoggerPtr_t LoggerFactory::getGenericLogger(const LoggerConfig& config) {
    // TODO: need to protect this whole method by a mutex
    std::string filename = config.getFileName();
    LoggerMapIt_t itLogger = mLoggerMap.find(filename);
    if (itLogger == mLoggerMap.end()) {
        LoggerPtr_t ptr(new SimpleLogger(config));
        mLoggerMap.insert(std::make_pair(filename, ptr));
        return ptr;
    } else {
        return itLogger->second;
    }
}
```

But you really should also completely check the answer of Jarod42.
The point is, that you have to decide about ownership of the logger objects.

Using `std::unique_ptr` and references (like seen in Jarod42's answer) is more efficient code, because `std::shared_ptr` (which even means "shared ownership") is more expensive than `std::unique_ptr`.

But on the other side, you have to take care about static initialization and deinitialization, because of your global `LoggerFactory::mLoggerMap` instance.

You might solve that by using e.g. a singleton pattern getter function (assuming that you might logging even from other global instances c'tors). This might also help against issues on application shoutdown (deinitialization order of static instances).

Comment: as you can see, I'd also changed your `typedef` against C++11 `using` statements.

Comment: didn't even know about "using" until now. Thanks.

Comment: Some short addition: there is a "=" missing in line 2 :)

Answer (score 3):

This line will "take" the `unique_ptr` from the `std::map`

```
if(itLogger != mLoggerMap.end()){
    return std::move(itLogger->second);
}
```

Therefore, the `unique_ptr` that is in `mLoggerMap` where `itLogger` was just pointing is now `nullptr`. If you point back to that element later, or from another thread, trying to do anything with that `unique_ptr` will cause a problem because you `std::move` the pointer earlier.

If you **don't** want to relinquish ownership of the pointer, but rather you just want to have access to the pointer, you could also change the signature of your function to return the underlying raw pointer

```
AbstractLogger* LoggerFactory::getGenericLogger(const LoggerConfig& config)
```

Then you can say

```
if(itLogger != mLoggerMap.end()){
    return itLogger->second.get();
}
```

Otherwise, if you **do** want to relinquish/transfer ownership to the caller you should likely remove the element from the map, then return the move'd pointer.

Comment: But if I remove the objects from the map, then there is no longer a central interface which is able to tell me if this file is already is use. And therefore the method is not able to return the correct logger object again (to possibly another thread). Or am I wrong? Moreover, while learning C++, I was told (maybe 1000 times) that raw pointers are bad and that I have to release the memory by myself afterwards. Now I'm confused...

Comment: @little_planet That sounds like the Java way.

Comment: @little_planet If the map "owns" the pointers, then that is the only object that should keep them as `unique_ptr`. Everyone else calling this function merely needs raw pointers, as it sounds like they do not own them, they are just looking at them. So when `LoggerFactory::mLoggerMap` falls out of scope, it will clean up all the pointers.

Comment: This seems reasonable. But just to make sure I got everything right. What is the exact difference between using `unique_ptr` in my static method + passing raw pointers to the application as you proposed OR using `shared_ptr`s?

Comment: @little_planet `shared_ptr` would imply that the map could lose ownership at some point but the object would still be in use, thus shared ownership.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you transfer ownership, so the map contain afterwards empty `unique_ptr`. So second call retrieve empty `unique_ptr`.

As it seems you don't want ownership transfer, I would write the code as following:

```
AbstractLogger& LoggerFactory::getGenericLogger(const LoggerConfig& config)
{
    const std::string& filename = config.getFileName();
    auto& logger = mLoggerMap[filename]; // insert (default) empty unique_ptr if not present.
    if (logger == nullptr) {
       logger = std::make_unique<SimpleLogger>(config);
    }
    return *logger;
}
```

Comment: This made the whole unique_ptr matter more clear for me. Thank you Jarod.

Comment: But the new logger instance should be added (inserted) to mLoggerMap, isn't it? … or … if I see right, this will be done by that "insert (default) empty unique_ptr" ... isn't it? If so, then - wow, very nice approach.

Comment: @Joe: `std::map::operator[]` inserts default value when key is not present. In that case, I overwrite value with via `make_unique`. It is true that this method cannot differentiate between existent empty `unique_ptr`, and absent key, but in any case, here, I want to initialize to usable value.

Comment: @little_planet: for this, I prefer you to use this approach, but you should IMHO use a singleton pattern for your static `mLoggerMap` instance.

Comment: @Joe Yes, I changed my code according to Jarods proposal. Anyway, I think it is not harmful to leave your answer marked as the solution. I will edit my original post accordingly.